# Updating many instances in one view

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I'm starting with Grails and I don't know how should I face the following use case.

The app is about sports results prediction, so I have in my domain "Match" and "Prediction", and I want to have one view where the user can update all the predictions of matches that haven't been played yet.

So far I've defined a method in my "PredictionController" that searches all the already existing predictions of games that have to be played and generates new Prediction instances for any new Match with a date higher than now. I've created a view for that method and I'm getting correctly all the predictions that I should complete or update, and I've defined in my controller another method for the form sumbission (so I'm trying to resolve this in the same way that the 'create' and 'update' scaffolded methods work).

My question is, How can I access to all the Predictions modified by my view? How can I send all the predictions to my update method? Is it defining a hidden field with a variable containing all the collection?

This is the form in my GSP view:

```
<g:form action="savePredicctions">
<fieldset>
<g:each in="${predictions}">
    <li>
    <div>
        ${it.match.homeTeam}
        <g:field name="${it.match}.homeGoals" type="number" value="${it.homeGoals}" />
    </div>
    -
    <div> 
        <g:field name="${it.match}.awayGoals" type="number" value="${it.awayGoals}" /> 
        ${it.match.awayTeam}
    </div>                  
    </li>
</g:each>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="submit">
    <g:submitButton />
</fieldset>
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [command](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) object to store the instances of Prediction.

```
@Validateable
class PredictionCommand {
  //data binding needs a non-null attribute, so we use ListUtils.lazyList
  List<Prediction> predictions = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Prediction))

}
```

In your view, you need to control the index of your list, and send the attributes of Prediction to the controller:

```
<g:each in="${predictions}" status="i">
  <g:textField name="predictions[$i].homeGoals" />
  <g:textField name="predictions[$i].awayGoals" />
</g:each>
```

And in your controller you can use `bindData()` to bind `params` to your command:

```
class CommandController {
  def save() {
    PredictionCommand command = new PredictionCommand()
    bindData(command, params)
    println command.predictions
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll read more about Commands and try this solution